# Prometheus Empty query result using node-exporter

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter, prometheus-alertmanager

I use prometheus(node-exporter) but It doesn't work the way I want it to.

1. I have two node-exporter and I can find it
   [image]
2. But I can't get node-exporter CPU
   [image]
   [image]

How I get node-exporter CPU and run query ?

Answer (score 0):

The time range is too short, change the "[1s]" to "[5m]" and it will work.

Comment: I fixed it, but it still doesn't work

Comment: What just does "node_cpu_seconds_total" return? If it works, add the other items, one by one, for example, add the mode="idle", then the "rate" function, etc. This will help to find the issue.